# Why use independence test and not normality test for structure identification?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, causality

In the book 'Elements of causal inference', the code below is used an example for structure identification.

```
library(dHSIC)
library(mgcv)
X <- rnorm(200)
Y <- X^3 + rnorm(200)
modelforw <- gam(Y ~ s(X))
modelbackw <- gam(X ~ s(Y))
dhsic.test(modelforw$residuals, X)$p.value
dhsic.test(modelbackw$residuals, Y)$p.value
```

The example is clear, but my doubt is, why is he using an independence test and not a normality test? Given that the data is normal, wouldn't it be easier to test for that?

Comment: You could explain in a bit more detail what is going on in the code?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in section 4.2.1 Additive Noise Models, here's an excerpt:

[image]

In this method they only need to check the independence of residuals from $x\sim y$ and $y\sim x$ models from $y$ and $x$ to see whether there is an asymmetry, which tells them whether there is causality

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, but how is this related to structure identification? Do you understand what the OP is doing? (I do not.)

Comment: @RichardHardy no idea